# Null Object Reference Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these codes that displays the first student record and first group record in my database in the Index page:

```
var studentToAdd = db.Students.FirstOrDefault();
var selectedGroup = db.Groups.FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.Name = studentToAdd.Firstname;
ViewBag.Group = selectedGroup.GroupName;
```

It works and it displays "Richard"  and "Group1" in my index page. But when I add this code that should add "Richard" to "Group1" I get a null object exception :

```
selectedGroup.Students.Add(studentToAdd);
```

How do i fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `var selectedGroup = db.Groups.FirstOrDefault()` returns a `Group` object whose `Students` property is null, I guess. You can find the variable that holds the null reference by setting a breakpoint and debugging your code.

The solution depends on what techniques you use and what your `Groups` class looks like (amongst others lazy loading on `virtual` properties). The constructor of the `Groups` class can also initialize an empty `Students` collection, to which you can then add entities with `.Add()`.

Comment: *You can find the variable that holds the null reference by ... debugging your code* OP debugging their code? What a novel idea..

Comment: @ta.speot.is I agree, it's much easier to put the code online and let others do that for you.

Comment: Thanks. But believe it or not I tried my best debugging my code before I posted this question. Maybe I'm just not debugging the right way.

Comment: @WannaCSharp how did you resolve it? And no problem, I gave you a hint how to debug this the next time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you try to add, at that point `selectedGroup.Students` property is `null`.

Do this

```
if (selectedGroup.Students == null)
    selectedGroup.Students = new List<Student>(); // If its a List

selectedGroup.Students.Add(studentToAdd);
```